# How do I let a float know on which column it is placed?

Tags: floats, conditionals, two-column

Is there a safe and sound way to let the insides of a float environment know on which column the float is placed?

Here is an examples that fails:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\blindfigure}{O{}}{
\begin{figure}[#1]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.35\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\if@firstcolumn I'm on the left\else I'm on the right\fi}
\end{figure}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\blindfigure[H]
\blindtext
\blindfigure[H]
\blindtext
\blindfigure[H]
\end{document}
```

The second float is reflowed to the second column so it gets tricked:

[image: floats and stuff]

I'd love to have a solution that works with all float targets (`hHtbp!`).

Comment: I think, querying the column occurs too late in the `\caption` command.

Comment: The caption is typeset at the moment the `figure` environment is processed, not when it is placed.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I figured that out; btw, I don't really care about the caption, I just used it to display the problem. I any case the whole content of `figure` is processed *before* the placement, so theoretically I have no access to placement information from the inside. One way could be hijacking the float mechanism and rewiring it into `process+fake placement+reprocess w/placement data+placement`. That really sounds daunting, though. I was hoping for some clever trick.

Comment: @egreg: Isn't the whole `twocolumn` algorithm a `box`-shifting, i.e. the box with the figure is typeset and nothing can be changed afterwards?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes: TeX must know the size of the float in order to be able to place it.

Comment: @egreg: Then there's no solution to this?